# 87C51 to AT89S51

Tags: assembly, 8051

We have old source files written in assembly for a P87C51 micro controller we are updating this to an AT89S52 micro controller. We try to load the same .hex file onto the new chip however it doesn't perform as expected. The main function of the code is to have a UART ISR and check the UART and send it along out. Any insight would be very helpful

There are some differences in the SFRs we noticed however the UART is supposed to run on the Timer2 which looks to be the same setup. The SFRs missing we don't appear to be using such as SLAVEADDRESS.

Comment: 1. check if the uploading works properly (for example flash a simple code that increments the ports)
2. if the above works, check the frequency 
3. ... and so on step by step you will find the issue.

Comment: I went through a lot of troubleshooting procedures. and the chip is performing correctly other than the UART. There is a another function of the code within the chip to check a DPRAM. The code correctly executes this function and is able to communicate with the DPRAM. From what I've seen the UART on timer2 should be the same and I can't find out why I am not triggering on a receive on the UART when all the interrupts are set.

Comment: Confused: AT89S51 or AT89S52? Did you try the code on an AT89S51?

Comment: the AT89S51 doesnt have timer2 and can only run create a baud rate on timer1. The baud rate I need to generate is 19200 timer 1 running on an 8 bit reload timer can't create this baud rate compared to timer 2 on the AT89S52 running on a 16 bit reload timer which is able to generate this baud rate. so an AT89S51 wouldn't be sufficient.

Comment: OK but your question title refers to AT89S51. Can you make the UART send some data so you can confirm it is running and the baud rate is 19200? Or loop TX back to RX and get receive working?